# Android Firebase don't retrieve data in simple chat app

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, authentication

I'm creating a simple chat app with Firebase Database and authentication.
It usually works fine, but if I don't run the app (run in my device por testing) for a while (an hour, more or less), Firebase doesn't retrieve any data and my Views are empty.

If I logout and log in again, it works fine, but about an hour later, if I stop the app, I don't receive any data. There aren't any other problems, just that. When I re-log in, it works like a charm.

I have no idea of what is happening, any ideas of what is possibly happening??

Thanks in advance,

Nacho.

I've got this in Log:

```
04-06 10:34:15.719 5392-5392/? E/Zygote: v2
04-06 10:34:15.720 5392-5392/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-06 10:34:15.721 5392-5392/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0   RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0009, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
04-06 10:34:15.785 5392-5392/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/nachomeriapps.proyect14-1/lib/arm64
04-06 10:34:15.860 5392-5392/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-06 10:34:15.870 5392-5419/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
04-06 10:34:15.890 5392-5419/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000029/n/arm64-v8a
04-06 10:34:15.920 5392-5419/? W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
04-06 10:34:15.920 5392-5419/? W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdze@88e1fa1
04-06 10:34:15.920 5392-5411/? W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdze@88e1fa1
04-06 10:34:15.922 5392-5421/? W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Comment: It sounds like your device is cutting the connection and Firebase is not able to restore it. It's hard for anyone to troubleshoot such problems without actually having the device in hand. The best I can recommend is that you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)), and check the logcat output for relevant messages.

Comment: Updated my answer. Is that what you were referring for?